# Best way to loading 5-10k SVGs at a time in React? "RangeError: Maximum call stack size exceeded"

Tags: html, css, reactjs

I am building a website that is sort of a virtual wall. I will have a large volume of SVGs (5k-10k) at a time, which I will display to the user. The website will allow the user to look around the wall and zoom in/out. When the user first lands on the page, I want the user to be zoomed out so they can see the whole wall, then choose to zoom in on parts of the wall. Since I need all of the images present, I think this rules out lazy loading.

The SVGs are stored locally, so the loading is not grabbing them from an API. On the react end, I'm just mapping this array of SVGs into a grid. Then its just the browser loading the SVGs within an  tag.

Currently when I try to load all of these images, I get the error `"RangeError: Maximum call stack size exceeded"`, but the images do end up loading and nothing is wrong except for this error in the console. Is there a recommended approach to loading a huge amount of images like this?

```
import { useState } from "react";
import loot from "../../assets/loot.json";
import { WallMinimap } from "./WallMinimap";
import { Zoom } from "./Zoom";
import "./styles.css";

const assets = loot.result;

export const Wall = () => {
  return (
    <div className="w-[100vw] bg-blue-100">
      <div className="flex flex-wrap bg-red-100 w-[5098px]">
        {assets.map((item, index) => {
          return (
            <div
              className="item w-[50px] h-[50px] m-[1px] bg-green-200 flex items-center justify-center"
              data-hl-color={"coral"}
              onMouseEnter={() => {
                setIndex(index);
              }}
              key={index}
            >
              <img src={item.image} alt="tile" />
            </div>
          );
        })}
      </div>
    </div>
  );
};
```

Comment: Can you show us some basic code e.g. how the first half dozen svgs are inserted - I don't currently understand how you are getting a call stackoverflow - not often seen on this site :) - if you haven't got anything nested but are just loading images. I could understand it if you were running out of storage perhaps.

Comment: Ah sorry @AHaworth, just updated the original post with the code example. I don't really see how this is causing a stack overflow either, especially since the browser does end up loading all of the images

Comment: Is it just that every time you start an image load something is added to the call stack (so the system can inform you when it’s loaded if required) and at some point it’s got so many load requests outstanding it hasn’t got room to remember on the call stack - but the underlying load request is still on the go OK. There don’t seem to be rules for how large the call stack has to be. You could test this by loading a few at a time then pausing then loading some more.